# Get count of credit cards that are expired

Tags: c#, object-oriented

Below is a sample implementation for getting the expired credit cards in the credit card list.I wrote a property and initialized it in the constructor. Need an opinion on if this is a proper way to implement it.

```
   public class User
    {
        private readonly List<CreditCard> creditCards;

        public int CountOfCreditCards
        {
            get
            {
                return counter;
            }
        }

        private static int counter;

        private User()
        {
            creditCards = new List<CreditCard>();
            counter = GetCountOfExpiredCreditCards();
        }

        public int GetCountOfExpiredCreditCards()
        {
            return creditCards.Count(x => x.ExpirationMonth <= DateTime.Now.Month);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question, although you're advised to wait at least a day before doing so.

Comment: this doesn't work, nothing can ever get assigned to `creditCards` because it is a private readonly and is never set anywhere.  you should have gotten a warning from Visual Studio and/or the compiler.  I am going to close this question, because you either don't have working code or you did not provide us with enough code to review this properly.

Comment: My bad, May be i should have read the rules before. I was trying to improve my concrete implementation of the class. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 5):

> If a class has one or more private constructors and no public constructors, other classes (except nested classes) cannot create instances of this class.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors

Make your constructor public.

There is an obvious bug in `GetCountOfExpiredCreditCards`  A card that expires in 01/19(January, 2019) will show up as expired if checked today.  Check for both year and month.

Comment: uggh..How did i miss that, Thanks for pointing out the expiration logic.

Answer (score 2):

Consistency is key when you're naming things. You have `counter`, `CountOfCreditCards` and a method called `GetCountOfExpiredCreditCards`. Your method is named perfectly but the other two are less precise. Try to be consistent.

Did you know about read-only auto properties? That would get rid of your counter field:

```
public int CountOfExpiredCreditCards { get; }

private User()
{
    creditCards = new List<CreditCard>();
    CountOfExpiredCreditCards = GetCountOfExpiredCreditCards();
}
```

I would argue that it's fine to just calculate the count on demand by making the method public and removing the property entirely.

You also use `DateTime.Now` which is the system *local* time. Timezones and DateTime handling are a very deep rabbit hole so just be aware that generally speaking, you would want to use `DateTime.UtcNow`, `DateTimeOffset`, or a third party like Noda Time's `ZonedDateTime`.

As an aside, you have the `counter` field as static. That means it's shared between all instances of `User` which is almost certainly not what you want.